# Select values from Access 2010 query calculated field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query in Access where I want to select a range of dates from a calculated field in the query.

The field is populated using the following expression:

```
DueDate: DateAdd("m",-([PMI job lookup table]![Frequency]),[Date])
```

I'd like to select everything from a certain month and year from this field.

For example I'd like to list all the jobs in say `May 2014`.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, add this criteria for the field of DueDate:

```
Between DateSerial(2014,5,1) And DateSerial(2014,5+1,0)
```

This will filter for dates between 2014-05-01 and 2014-05-31.